# How to use Contact Builder Data Model and Data Filters for Email Sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bestpractice, filters, contactbuilder

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Imagine we have an All Subscribers list and a few data extensions with the following attributes:

- All Subscribers => Subscrber Key, Email Address, First Name, Last Name
- Client => ClientReferenceNumber, PolicyStatus, ServicingAgentNumber
- Agent => AgentNumber, AgentFirstName, AgentLastName

In Contact Builder, I have created Data Extension links in order to setup the Foreign Key-like constraints as follows:

- Contacts (ContactKey) => Client (ClientReferenceNumber)

  - AND
- Client (ServicingAgentNumber) => Agent (AgentNumber)

So, this works fantastically in Journey Builder. I was able to create a Journey with an Audience Entry Source stemming from Client. Then, in the following step of the Audience setup (Contact Filter), I was able to filter the Entry Source such that I only allowed Clients to enter the Journey if, say, their corresponding Agent's First Name is equal to "Timmy". That's great!

However, when I go to perform an ad-hoc email send, I can't seem to access these auxiliary tables... For example, say I want to create an ad-hoc email send where I only send emails to Clients having Agent's with the First Name equal to "Timmy" again. If I try to create a "Data Filter" from the Client data extension, I do not see the ability to drill down into the Agent data extension to filter off of these Foreign table attributes.

What am I missing here? Am I going about this all wrong? Best practices for such endeavors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe - and more seasoned people feel free to correct me! - that Contact Builder isn't (yet) linked to Data Filters or Filtered Data Extensions.

What this means is that in order to work and create the same segments in sendable DE's (or just DE's), you need to create the same data relationships inside email studio.

Go to:

Email Studio => Subscribers => Data Relationships

Create the same relationships (links), as you've done in contact builder

Then you should be able to create the necessary filtered ad hoc audiences.

Comment: You sir, are the man! That's exactly what I was looking for; thanks again! I'll up-vote your answer as soon as I get 15 reputation points :)

Comment: Haha Thanks Andrew - happy it helped with what you where trying to achieve :)